# I can't find the git icon on VS Code Source Control window and initialize repository option is hidden

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, initialization, repository

On my VS code there is no git icon on the Source Control window. There is initialize repository button but it is hidden. I've added a screenshot also if anyone can help me with the issue.

[image: VS Code screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the message below "Initialize Repository"

> A valid git installation was not detected, more details can be found in the git output.

So make sure VSCode is launched from a session where git is in the `%PATH%`/`$PATH`.